# Converting number with leading zeros in integer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, convert, integer

I used this command to organize my treenumbers:

```
lpad("baumnummer", 6, '0')
```

So tree number 1 will be shown as "00001". I did this because in my layout lists every tree will be put into the right order.

Now I found another solution but I want to remove all the zeros beforehand from my Attribute table. How can I achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this expression with the [`to_int()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#to-int) function:

```
to_int("baumnummer")
-- to_int('000001') -> 1
```

If you wish to maintain the string field type, you could expand the expression above with the [`to_string()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#to-string) function to:

```
to_string(to_int("baumnummer"))
-- to_string(to_int('000001')) -> '1'
```

Additionally one can achieve the desired output with the [`format_number()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#format-number) function:

```
format_number("baumnummer",0,'de')
-- format_number('000001',0,'de') -> '1'
```